# Aggregate Data Using UNIX Time in SQL

Tags: sql, azure

I’ve seen many posts already discussing how to use DATEPARTS() to aggregate data based on a datetime, but I haven’t found anything discussing this for UNIX time specifically. My goal is to be able to aggregate data whether by sec, min, hr or day, based on the initial and final timestamps provided. For example: Say my datetimes are:

```
tstart = datetime('2023-05-22 07:00:00','TimeZone','UTC');
tstop = datetime('2023-05-23 07:00:00','TimeZone','UTC');
```

These convert to:

```
Tstart = "1684738800000000"
Tstop = "1684825200000000"
```

Which is the number of microseconds that have passed. The reason for this conversion to UNIX is because the dataset on the server side only has this timestamp format and not a datetime column. How can I do this for different agg types such as sec, min, hr, and day and scale multipliers of those? (ie. 2 seconds, 7 hours, etc.) such that if I have data frequency in microseconds, and I covert it to every 3 hours over the timetamps provided above, I get something like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdZbB.png)

I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to start with this as I haven't worked with UNIX time before.

Azure Data Structure I am trying to do agg/calc on:

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFqcr.png)

Comment: Here's an idea: first convert the unix time to date time/timestamp then aggregate as per your need. You may look into this reference on converstion:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#convert-to-dates-or-timestamps

Comment: I have to keep it as a unix timestamp since that is what the data on the server uses. There isn't a date time column. So I need to do the calculation/aggregation within the UNIX space.

Comment: I'm not saying to update the data in the table. What I'm saying is, write a query which will  cast unix timestamp to date time on the fly and then use that column as per your need. i.e. `select to_date(datime_in_string_format,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') event_date from some_table`.  could you share sample records that you have in your database? its  difficult to provide any solution without adequate information.

Comment: Does SQL just know how to convert the datetime to unix automatically then on the server side? I posted the structure of the data I am trying to access/do calc on. How can I share the table values such that it's not just an image? It won't let me copy it directly in the post nor attach any files.

Comment: @Sophia You can use [online markdown table generator](https://tableconvert.com/markdown-generator) and convert the table in markdown format and attach it in the question.

Comment: @Aswin Okay! Thank you! I will save that for the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to aggregate the data in the table by a 3-hour interval and calculate the average of `data1` and `data2` for each interval, you can follow the below approach.

**SQL code**

```sql
with
   cte1 as (SELECT  DATEADD(SECOND, timestamp / 1000000, '19700101') AS dt,* FROM  Mytable1),
   cte2 as (select DATEPART(hour,dt)-((DATEPART(hour, dt) + 0) % 3) as interval, cast(dt as date) as date_col,* from cte1)
select min(timestamp) as timestamp, avg(data1) as data1, avg(data2) as data2 from cte2 group by date_col,interval;
```

The first CTE (`cte1`) converts the Unix timestamps in the  `Mytable1`  table to datetime values using the  `DATEADD`  function.  The second CTE (`cte2`) calculates the 3-hour interval for each datetime value using the  `DATEPART`  function The final SELECT statement groups the data by date and interval and calculates the minimum timestamp and the average of  `data1`  and  `data2`  for each group.

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b9ZA3a2b)

Comment: Thank you for the response Aswin! I have a bunch of questions because I want to understand what your code is doing. Please be patient as I am new to SQL: 1) The real data set is a few million rows. When I try this code within the Azure SQL editor, it gives the following error: “[UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITH_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with name `hour` cannot be resolved. Did you mean one of the following? [`cte1`.`dt`, `cte1`.`day`, `cte1`.`year`, `cte1`.`date`, `cte1`.`month`].; line 3, pos 28”.

Comment: The “hour” is highlighted blue though so it is being recognized as a function so I am not sure why it doesn’t like it other than it requires a define input argument.

Comment: 2) I’ve never used the AS function and had to look it up. I noticed that you interchange the order and I am trying to understand why that works. Is it because in SQL, the order for it doesn’t matter? Say for the dt assignment: you assign all of line 2 to cte1. But you also assign part of line 2 to dt and the order of the assignment is revered.

Comment: 3) I also haven’t used dateadd before. What is the third input argument doing in the dateadd function? Is that supposed to be the starting time being referenced for unix definition? If so, I converted the third input argument for it to datetime and found it to be: Monday, August 17, 1970 12:15:01 AM GMT. I assume this was just meant to be an estimate starting position if this was the case? 4) What does the % 3 do in line 3? 5) If interval is a function, how are you able to assign a function to a user defined object?

Comment: Answer to 3rd question: Refer [this](https://whatthefact.bi/power-bi/dax/convert-unix-timestamp-to-date-or-datetime-format-in-power-bi/) for what is unix timestamp? and how to convert unix timestamp to datetime format?

Comment: Answer to 3, and 4 : Check this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zn1GvoJp).. I broke the entire code down to simple steps. This would explain the usage of `%3`.

Comment: Answer to 5: interval is not a function. It is column name that is created in CTE1

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand now what's going on. But, when I try the code, it still gives me the error I mentioned before. I changed the query slightly to avoid using the hour function:

WITH cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        (timestamp / (1000000 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 3)) AS interval, 
        logical, 
        data1, 
        data2 
    FROM Mytable1
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        interval, 
        AVG(logical) AS avg_logical, 
        AVG(data1) AS avg_data1, 
        AVG(data2) AS avg_data2
    FROM cte1 
    GROUP BY interval
)
SELECT * FROM cte2;

Comment: The issue now though is that I get this error: [UNRESOLVED_COLUMN.WITHOUT_SUGGESTION] A column or function parameter with the name 'interval' cannot be resolved. I also noticed that interval is highlighted in a light blue so I think it's reserved by the SQL version I am using? Either way, I changed interval to "time_interval" and the same error. I am using Spark SQL on Azure.

Comment: Okay..Just understood the error. Syntax for `sql` , `spark sql`  are different. SInce the question has `sql` tag, i provided code in sql

Comment: Are you using Azure Synapse analytics?

Comment: Okay, will do. I actually didn't know myself that there were different versions of SQL in the first place. I am still learning and will post a new question.